# Java: Sending facebook credentials

Tags: java, facebook, authentication, credentials

I am working on a program that will download a facebook page so I have the html. However, when I download it, I get the facebook page that isn't logged in.

Is there a way to somehow send my facebook login so facebook thinks the program is logged in, so I get the correct html?

Comment: Apache has a nice [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). You're going to need to do at least one http post/get to get the expected html page.

Comment: Is this something for yourself, or is this something that will be distributed to others?

Comment: @user1329572 The original question doesn't say anything about this being on a web server.

Comment: @saluce, Not sure I understand your point.

Comment: This is on my desktop and just for me.

Comment: @saluce, the HttpClient is simply a Java library (or group of them now, I think) that provides a clean API for doing HTTP requests.  It's not part of the Apache httpd product, it just happens to be from the Apache foundation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information from Facebook, you should be using the API available to you at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/
. The API provides access to most data that you would want, and it does so with OAuth authentication and JSON responses, which both have a lot of support in the development community (you will be able to find several libraries to handle these types of data without having to code it yourself). There are also samples, SDKs for a number of different programming language, and lots of good information.

Otherwise, if you want the HTML specifically, you can use the components at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html
. This is some code that you can use to get a HTTP page...

```
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.facebook.com");

  // Send the request
  DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

  // Get the response code
  if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    // Success
    String responseMessage = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    // do something with the response here
  }
```

If you need to send data, such as sending the login information to Facebook, you can use `HttpPost` instead of `HttpGet`, and attach your login information.

You should be warned, however, that Facebook is pretty strict at banning people that use HTTP requests rather than their API, so I would discourage you away from doing this. I direct you to the Facebook Platform Policy here... https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com/